# If $u$ is in fiber under given group homomorphism then where is $u^{-1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Suppose we have $\phi: G \to H$ is a group homomorphism, s.t. $\phi^{-1}(a)=X \in G/K$ for some $a\in H$, and $K=\ker\phi$. If $u$ is in fiber under $\phi$ can we determine where is $u^{-1}$?

Comment: Do you mean $u \in \phi^{-1}(a) = X$? Have you thought about what $X^{-1}$ might be? It is true that $XX^{-1} = K$?

Comment: If we know that $(aX)^n = a^n X$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $X^{-1} = X$. Or I'm missing some concept.

Comment: If $X = \{uk:k\in K\}$ ,then $XX^{-1} = \{ukk^{-1}u^{-1}=e:k\in K\}$.

Comment: Not quite. $XX^{-1} = \{ukk'^{-1}u^{-1}:k,k'\in K\}$. But since $K$ is normal,  $uK = Ku$, so $u(kk'^{-1}) = k_1u$ for some $k_1 \in K$, that is: $XX^{-1} = \{k_1uu^{-1} = k_1e = k_1: k_1 \in K\} = K$. In particular, $X^{-1} = (uK)^{-1} = u^{-1}K$. Now show $\phi(u^{-1})$ *must* be $a^{-1}$.